# search functionality in Django ORM

Tags: django

if there is two type of data in table :'ABC-DE' and 'ABCDE'
if someone search with space and underscore or hyphen so how to search for it without the regular expression

Comment: Is that a very specific data format, or just one example? Could you be a little clearer on what you're trying to do? Is it to exclude anything that isn't a letter (number too?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @michjnich i think its clear enough.  he just want to ignore special characters to match search results with Db values

Comment: It's really not clear. All special chars? Only "-"`? Is that a specific format for some code for example.

Answer (score 0):

`Q` is the best.

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

An example:

```
posts.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(tags__name__icontains=query) | Q(body__icontains=query)).order_by('-updated').distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so good with response time but you can do like this:

This query will ignore `space, hyphen`
and you should remove all spec characters from search input as well.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower, Replace


search_input = (search_input.replace(" ","").replace("-","").replace("_","")).lower()
```

```
Post.object.annotate(name_lower=Replace(Replace(Lower("name"), Value(" "), Value("")), Value("-"), Value(""))).filter(name_lower__icontains=search_input)
```